# scheme - how to retrieve each element of list as an integer

Tags: scheme

I am very new to scheme, need a small help. I want to pick each element of a list
as an integer and do some processing.

```
(define (myfunc a b)
...
)
```

I will call the funciton as follows:

```
(myfunc '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2))
```

inside myfunc , I need to pick each element in the second list as an integer and do some calculations. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by pick each element in the second list as an integer? The elements of those lists are already numbers. What do you want to do with those lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (myfunc a-list indices)
  (define (get i) (list-ref a-list i))
  (map get indices))

(my-func '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2))
```